# taking input of a string word by word

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++. I was just playing around with it and came across a problem which involved taking input of a string word by word, each word separated by a whitespace. What I mean is, suppose I have

```
   name  place animal
```

as the input. I want to read the first word, do some operations on it. Then read the second word, do some operations on that, and then read the next word, so on.

I tried storing the entire string at first with getline  like this

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
     string t;
     getline(cin,t);
     cout << t; //just to confirm the input is read correctly
    }
```

But then how do I perform operation on each word and move on to the next word?

Also, while googling around about C++ I saw at many places, instead of using "using namespace std" people prefer to write "std::"
with everything. Why's that? I think they do the same thing. Then why take the trouble of writing it again and again?

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Put the line in a stringstream and extract word by word back:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string t;
    getline(cin,t);

    istringstream iss(t);
    string word;
    while(iss >> word) {
        /* do stuff with word */
    }
}
```

Of course, you can just skip the getline part and read word by word from `cin` directly.

And here you can read [why is `using namespace std` considered bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I tried reading with cin. But since the words are separated by a whitespace, cin seemed to read only the first word. A simple 
    cin t;
    cout t;
shows that. Hence I switched to getline.

Comment: @jrok getting compilation error on the code you gave.

 error: variable ‘std::istringstream iss’ has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: @zack Did you include `<sstream>`?

Comment: @jrok what's the "iss" for ?

Comment: what exactly is `istringstream` ? A modified string type?

Comment: check **this page** :)  : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/

Comment: Just wanted to ask the meaning of : while(iss >> word) : what exactly it is doing ?

Answer (score 6):

(This is for the benefit of others who may refer)

You can simply use **cin** and a **char** array. The cin input is delimited by the first whitespace it encounters.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    char word[50];
    cin>>word;
    while(word){
        //Do stuff with word[]
        cin>>word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getline is storing the entire line at once, which is not what you want. A simple fix is to have three variables and use cin to get them all. C++ will parse automatically at the spaces.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    //now you have your three words
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what particular "operation" you're talking about, so I can't help you there, but if it's changing characters, read up on string and indices. The C++ documentation is great. As for using namespace std; versus std:: and other libraries, there's already been a lot said. Try [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265039/using-std-namespace) on StackOverflow to start.

Comment: Number of words in the string are unknown. Any method to read the words with cin then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683302/how-to-split-a-space-separated-string-into-multiple-strings-in-c

Comment: you can do something with getline and deliminating characters too http://www.minich.com/education/wyo/cplusplus/cplusplusch10/getfunction.htm