# Reading strings until end of line?

Tags: c++

Is there some way to read consecutive words separated by spaces as strings until end of line is found in C++? To be precise, I'm working on an algorithmic problem and the input goes like:

```
some_word1 some_word2 some_word3 (...) some_wordn
other_data
```

And the trick is I don't know how many words will there be in the first line, just that I should read them as separate words for further processing. I know I could use `getline()`, but after that I'd have to work char-by-char to write each word in a new string when space occurs. Not that it's a lot of work, I'm just curious if there's a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you have to work character by character after using `getline`?
The usual way of parsing line oriented input is to read line by line,
using `getline`, and then use an `std::istringstream` to parse the line
(assuming that is the most appropriate parsing tool, as it is in your
case).  So to read the file:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
    std::istringstream parse( line );
    //  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sstream` and combine it with `getline()`, which is something you already know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string fl;
    std::getline(std::cin, fl); // get first line

    std::istringstream iss(fl);
    std::string word;
    while(iss >> word) {
        std::cout << "|" << word << "|\n";
    }

    // now parse the other lines
    while (std::getline(std::cin, fl)) {
      std::cout << fl << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a b
|a|
|b|
a
a
g
g
t
t
```

You can see that the spaces are not saved.

---

Here you can see relevant answers:

1. [Split a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)
2. [Taking input of a string word by word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318980/taking-input-of-a-string-word-by-word)

Comment: And since the question is a duplicate, why answer and not vote to close?

Comment: Oh I thought that we should answer the question, wait for a question to be accepted and then vote for duplicate @jpw. Guess I was wrong! Should I delete the answer?

Comment: Nah, don't bother. It won't be closed now anyway.

Comment: OK, I will have it in mind for the future. I will vote for a duplicate too. Thanks @jpw

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read the complete line as a string and split the string into a vector of strings.
Splitting a string can be found from this question [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

```
string linestr;
cin>>linestr;
string buf; // Have a buffer string
stringstream ss(linestr); // Insert the string into a stream

vector<string> tokens; // Create vector to hold our words

while (ss >> buf)
    tokens.push_back(buf);
```