# why does 'Do while' loop act this way?

Tags: c++, input, while-loop, user-input

When I type some character this program prints a single message. When I type two characters it prints `hello world` twice and when `aaaaa` is typed, five `hello world` messages are printed and so on! Why?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char nnn;
    do {
        cout << "hello world" << endl;
        cin >> nnn;
    } while ((nnn != 'y'));

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a result:

```
hello world
d
hello world
ffff
hello world
hello world 
hello world
hello world
y
```

Comment: What were you expecting to happen, instead?

Comment: i expected it to post only one sentence.

Comment: You did input 5 non-'y' characters, and the code prints `hello world` for each one (plus one at the very beginning).

Comment: so is there another func that i can replace 'cin' with that only reads the input as a whole not one char by one?

Comment: Not sure if you mean whole words or whole lines. See for example [taking input of a string word by word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318980/taking-input-of-a-string-word-by-word) which has examples of both.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're reading into `char`, `cin >> nnn;` will read one character per iteration, i.e. it goes through all the `f`'s in `ffff` only because of the loop. It stops and waits for your further input when there is nothing to read.

If you wanted to read the whole word/line at once, you should have used `operator>>`/`std::getline` with `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

if you input `ffff` it will consider that you type it four times and will print out "hello world" four times so try to change the char ==> string to avoid this problem.